# Adjusting space before and after a latex beamer block

Tags: beamer, spacing, environments

I wanted to ask you if there is a better way to adjust the spacing between two `beamer` blocks:

```
\documentclass[slidestop]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vspace*{-3pt}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{-3pt}}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{block}{block 1}
Test
\end{block}
\begin{block}{block 2}
Test
\end{block}
\begin{block}{block 3}
Test
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: What kind of way do you think of? Or what's wrong with that?

Comment: I would like to change a latex beamer variable which takes care of the spacing. I also think that the spacing is done in a relative fashion and I would like to adjust the ratios. If you know how to manipulate beamer to achieve the same result, I would be happy.

Comment: @7asd44 The original definition of `block begin` includes a `\vksip\bigskipamount` at the start and the of `block end` `\vskip\smallskipamount`. You could change this skips but this would probably break more than that it helps. You can re-define these templates to say `\vspace*{\myverticalskip}` where you can set `\myverticalskip` as you wish. What do you mean with ratios? You can insert manually `\vfill`s to space these blocks out.

Comment: @7asd44 If you want the spacing between the blocks to scale with your chosen font size, then you can use `em` or `ex` instead of `pt` for `\vspace{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[To get this off the unanswered list]

There is no 'better' way, as there is no hook built into `beamer` for adjusting the distance here. However, what is not clear is why you want to do this in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vskip -\bigskipamount}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vskip -\bigskipamount}
```

is slightly better solution.

Comment: Maybe it should be `\smallskipamount` at the end (see comment to the question of @Qrrbrbirlbel).

Answer (score 2):

I find this better in my case

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vfill}
```